# React JS - Material UI ListItem (with Collapse API) onClick expand only one at a time close other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, material-ui

React JS - Material UI ListItem (with Collapse API) onClick expand only one at a time close other. on click i need to open only one item at time. and when i click other the present opened should close.requirement is sidenavbar when i open click any menu , one should open . remaining or others should close

```
const isExpandable = items && items.length > 0;
      const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
      const [menu, setMenu] = useState(false);
      // const { value, setValue } = useContext(SiderBarContext)
      const { expand, setExpand } = useContext(SiderBarContext)
      function handleClick() {
        // setOpen(!open);
  
        setMenu(!menu)
          setOpen(prevState => ({
            open: !prevState
          }))
        // setValue(!open);
        setExpand(true)
      }
    const MenuItemRoot = (
        <>
          {isExpandable ? <AppMenuItemComponent
            className={isExpandable && menu ? classes.menuItemActiveMore : classes.menuItemActiveLess}
            link={link}
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
            {/* Display an icon if any */}
            {!!Icon && (
              <ListItemIcon className={classes.menuItemIcon}>
                {<Icon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
            )}
            <ListItemText primary={name} inset={!Icon} />
            {/* Display the expand menu if the item has children */}
            {isExpandable && !open && <ArrowDropDownIcon />}
            {isExpandable && open && <ArrowDropDownIcon />}
          </AppMenuItemComponent> : <AppMenuItemComponent
            className={classes.menuItem}
            link={link}
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
            {/* Display an icon if any */}
            {!!Icon && (
              <ListItemIcon className={classes.menuItemIcon}>
                {/* <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src={Icon} className={classes.iconImage}/> */}
                {<Icon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
            )}
            <ListItemText primary={name} inset={!Icon} />
            {/* Display the expand menu if the item has children */}
            {isExpandable && !open && <ArrowDropDownIcon />}
            {isExpandable && open && <ArrowDropDownIcon />}
          </AppMenuItemComponent>}
        </>
      );
    
      const MenuItemChildren = isExpandable ? (
        <Collapse className={classes.menuChildItem} in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
          {/* <Divider /> */}
          <List component="div" disablePadding >
            {items.map((item, index) => (
              <>
                <AppMenuItem {...item}  key={index} />
              </>
            ))}
          </List>
        </Collapse>
      ) : null;
    
      return (
        <>
          {MenuItemRoot}
          {MenuItemChildren}
        </>
      );
    };
```

Comment: can you add a minimal reproducible example in codeSandbox ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-hugle-s4bvg?file=/src/AppMenuItem.js --- please check this link i used the same method

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-hugle-s4bvg?file=/src/AppMenuItem.js -- please check the link i used the same method and format

Comment: it would be great ... if u could help..@Shyam